# Multiple websockets on same page

Tags: web, real-time

Can I have multiple websockets on a single webpage? I want to implement a real time chat application just like facebook. Also can you please tell how facebook handles multiple users chats at the same time ? Whether only one websocket is being opened for chat or multiple websockets are opened and configuration is done on server side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just googled many areas and got to the conclusion that we must implement one websocket in one webpage & can send more data which help in identifying what type of message & to whom it must be delivered like in my case I can send sender's name and receiver's name with that message to the backend server with the only websocket opened accordingly.

> We can also have multiple websockets on one page but it is not recommended